# how to update pictures when searching in table view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller

I made a table view with a search bar. Some pictures are in the following Google Drive: [drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B66972SsSRztcHAtTjJMbVFldVk&usp=sharing)

The code is mentioned below:

```
import UIKit

class WinkelTableView: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var winkels = ["Hunkemöller","Blokker","Standaard"]
    var fotos = [UIImage(named: "hunk"),UIImage(named: "Blokker"), UIImage(named: "Standaard")]
    private var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var filteredShops = [String]()
    var filteredShopspics = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    }

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    //filter through the shops

    if let searchTerm = self.searchController.searchBar.text {
        self.filteredShops = self.winkels.filter {   $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchTerm) }
    } else {
        self.filteredShops = []
    }

    //update results tableView
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.searchController.searchBar.text == "" {
        return self.winkels.count
    } else {
        return self.filteredShops.count
    }

    }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if self.searchController.searchBar.text == "" {
        cell.titel.text = self.winkels[indexPath.row]
        cell.foto.image = fotos[indexPath.row]

    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredShops[indexPath.row]

    }

    return cell
    }


}
```

I'd like to know how i can keep the pictures and the other label mentioned with underneath the name of the shop as well when i'm searching. Right now I can only see the name of the shop.. You'll see this in the pics as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your model and setup is more complicated than you need it to be, based upon the fact that you want to use the same type of cells to display your results as normal.

It's going to take some modification to simplify, so bear with me:

1. Remove `resultsController`.
2. Change searchController declaration to `private var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`
3. Everywhere you use `if tableView == self.tableView` instead do `if self.searchController.searchBar.text == ""'
4. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you're not accessing your `filteredPics` when setting up the other cell - in fact you should be setting up both parts just like you did in the prior check.
5. Bonus - here's a way to simplify your filter function:

   ```
   if let searchTerm = self.searchController.searchBar.text {
       self.filteredShops = self.winkels.filter {   $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchTerm) }
    }else{
        self.filteredShops = []
   }
   ```
6. To add on to (5), you may want to create a small data structure to hold your data as a combination of a string and an image. Try `let data = [(text: String, image: UIImage)]` - you can then access it via `data[index.row].text` for example, and your filtering would be `$0.text.contains...`. Your data model would then be simplified to `data` and `filteredData`.
7. To re-create your model for (6), do `var data: [(text: String, image: UIImage)] = [(text: "Hunkemöller", image: UIImage(named: "hunk")), ...]`

Comment: hi sschale, thanks for the answer. When i remove `resultsController`, what should i do with all my declarations in which this variable is mentioned? (eg. `self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)`)

Comment: Like I mentioned above, `UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`

Comment: I did steps one to three and step 5, and tried to do step four this way: `cell.foto.image = self.filteredShopspics[indexPath.row]`, which failed. You can see the error message in the "error.png" file in google drive (link in the original post). Also I uploaded a movie of what my app does when I delete the previously mentioned code. 
As for step six, i had no idea how to use the data variable (since it's an array with two different structures, and i'm a real newbie at xcode..), thanks for that info though, i will try to use that simplification once i get to know more about the coding.

Comment: So the reason that (4) fails is that you're not currently updating your filtered images array - take a look at newly added (7) as to how to create that new data array that you can filter once.

Comment: Hmm, i tried step 7, but it gives me following error: "cannot assign to immutable expression of type '[(text: String, image: UIImage)].Type' (aka 'Array<(text: String, image: UIImage)>.Type')"

Comment: I'm gonna try this another way, which is more useful for my app, thanks for the help though, I did learn quite a bit!